# Content floats above the sidebar in my Tumblr theme in Internet Explorer 9. How can I fix that?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, tumblr

Here's my Tumblr theme.

http://lt-chocolate.tumblr.com/

I checked it on Internet Explorer and the content is floating above the sidebar. Is there anyway I can fix it?

Here's the CSS I have for the content section.

```
#content {
background-color: #F2EBD9;
float: right;
width: 1200px;
height: 100%;
margin-right: 25px;
position: relative;
bottom: 296px;
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: the content is floating above the sidebar in other browsers as well.

Comment: How can I fix it so that way it doesn't do that in other browsers? In Google Chrome, it doesn't.

Comment: Please check in all browsers (clear cache first). I just checked and the content is floating above the sidebar in chrome too. Check in firefox as well.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this in firebug and it works for me

```
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 350px;/*change this size to your needs*/
}
#content {
    background-color: #F2EBD9;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;/*change this size to your needs*/
}
```

Comment: @LisaRamos that depends of your needs. in this case, float:right would stick the content to the right side. both would work on your website, just you'll need to play a bit with margin/padding. please dont forget to mark this answer as answer if it solved your issues. :)